# WorkManager listen for state change

Tags: android, android-jetpack, androidx, android-workmanager

I am enqueueing work with the following:

```
OneTimeWorkRequest myWork =
    new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(MyWorker.class)
    .build();
WorkManager.getInstance().enqueue(myWork);
```

When the work has finished, I want to enqueue another `OneTimeWorkRequest`.  Basically, I always what there to be a work scheduled, so that when one is completed (or cancelled by the system) I want another in its place.  This make it a bit like a `PeriodicWorkRequest` but there are reasons why `PeriodicWorkRequest` isn't appropriate (basically I need fine control over excluded times for the work to start, which isn't possible via the `Contraints` set on a single repeating work item).

Is there a way of listening for a state change for the work, so that I can react when the work status has changed to `SUCCEEDED` or `CANCELLED`, and enqueue another work item then?  I know that I could get `LiveData` with [this method](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/WorkManager#getWorkInfosByTagLiveData(java.lang.String)) but I think that requires explicitly requesting the `LiveData` periodically and checking status.  What I want is a listener that will fire when the status changes.

Comment: When you want to trigger work second time ?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK when the first work as completed or is cancelled... so that I never have two works in parallel but the next one is started as soon as it is detected that the first one is completed or cancelled

Comment: Have you tried schedule same work with different tag and some `setInitialDelay` in doWork()  just before returning SUCCESS ?

Comment: That is basically what I am doing now (except that I schedule the new work at the start of `doWork()` just in case something goes wrong with the rest of the processing in that function and it never reaches the end!).  But what happens if the scheduled work is cancelled by the system before it is ever run... so that `doWork()` is never called and the next work is never scheduled... left orphaned with no 'next' work enqueued.  Maybe I can enqueue another work using `ListenableWorker.onStopped()`?  I just thought there might be an all-encompassing state change listener.